# Only the text in a ListBox item is selectable, the space outside of the text is not selectable

Tags: wpf, xaml, listbox, selectionchanged

I have a WPF ListBox whose items are TextBlocks. When I click on the text the SelectionChanged handler is called as expected. However, if I click inside the item, but not directly over the text the handler is not called. This is more apparent when the text items are of widely varying lengths. If I have two items:

foo
exclamation

The "foo" item has a lot of space to the right which doesn't respond to the click

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate">
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

...

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListItemSelected" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listbox datatemplate - item only selectable by clicking a subelement, not just anywhere on the item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543813/listbox-datatemplate-item-only-selectable-by-clicking-a-subelement-not-just-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the following works, but it seems rather verbose...

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListItemSelected" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">
       <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

Any ideas on how to do this more concisely? Or a way to put this in the ItemTemplate? I couldn't find a way to do the same in the template.

The orig without that was just:

```
<ListBox SelectionChanged="ListItemSelected" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try.  You can take away the background color but that will show you how big the TextBlock is.

```
     Background="Beige" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
```

Comment: that does make it show up beige so I can see the size clearly, but the horizontalalignment property doesn't make it full width

Comment: Then give this a try  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the extra white space you are clickin on is "inside" your `ListBox`. Are you sure your `ListBox` is spanned across that much width?

Coz it doesnt seem to happen in my case.... (following `ListBox` is a child of a `Window`)

```
 <Window x:Class="WpfApplicationPathToImage.Window4"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window4" Height="100" Width="100">
    <ListBox SelectionChanged="ListBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                <TextBlock Text="Text1"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Text2"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Text3"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Text4"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Text5"/>
                <TextBlock Text="Text6"/>
            </x:Array>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
    </ListBox>
 </Window>
```

My `ListBox_SelectionChanged` is correctly called even if I click the white space outside the item level `TextBlock` boundaries (provided that I am actually clicking somewhere **inside** the `ListBox`).

Comment: Yes I'm sure. I could have to do with the theme I'm using, not sure. I plugged your code into one of the screens of my app with two changes: I made the background of the TextBlock in the DataTemplate green and I changed the text "Text3" to "Text3muchlonger".

The hover state shows the same "clickable" area that is recognized by SelectionChanged. This first image shows the list when the mouse pointer directly over the text "Text5" (http://i55.tinypic.com/2s940fd.png). This second image shows list when the mouse pointer is to the right of the text "Text5" (http://i56.tinypic.com/6znbpd.png)